# How global SetWindowsHookEx manages to inject dll into all threads?

Tags: windows, hook, dll-injection, setwindowshookex

[image]

I created 2 hooks in my host application. 1st is `WH_MOUSE` set specifically for Taskbar's thread. 2nd is global `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook (`dwThreadId` is set to 0).

As you can see in Process Explorer, the "local" hook actually injected my dll into specific explorer.exe thread. However, there is no indication that my 2nd global hook got injected into any other processes, yet it still works perfectly... Moreover, it also works for all the new processes I start, even after the hook was set! How `SetWindowsHookEx` manages that?

I read that it only applies to processes that load `user32.dll`. My weak suspicion is that in a case of global hook, Windows somehow injects my custom dll code into `user32.dll` "hook-chain". And then, when new process that loads `user32.dll` is started, it automatically loads my hook with it? Is this correct or is there some other mechanism at work?

Answer (score 0):

`_LL` (low-level) hooks are not injected anywhere, win32k (the kernel part of the window manager) calls the hook callback function directly. This is why that thread needs a message loop. Low-level hooks are always "global".

MSDN says:

> Be aware that the WH_MOUSE, WH_KEYBOARD, WH_JOURNAL*, WH_SHELL, and low-level hooks **can** be called on the thread that installed the hook rather than the thread processing the hook.

You should think of hooks as having 3 modes:

- Low-level (keyboard and mouse only)
- Thread specific
- All threads

The last two might require Windows to inject the .dll.